# UWP/WinRT: On Microsoft's first party apps, typing is smoothly animated, how can this effect be enabled for a TextBox or RichEditBox?

Tags: textbox, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, richeditbox

When typing in many of Microsoft's first-party apps, such as Office or the Windows 10 stock Mail app, text entry is smoothly animated (discussed [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/66908/office-2013-smooth-cursor-while-typing), among many other places). The text does not simply appear and the cursor does not simply teleport to its next position. Instead, there is a transition animation that causes the cursor to smoothly move to its new position.

Is there a flag or any other method to enable this same effect in apps we develop ourselves?

I've looked through the API documentation for the [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.aspx) and the [RichEditBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox.aspx) but I'm not seeing anything.

If there is not such a built-in method, how would I go about implementing this myself, perhaps by rolling my own TextBox?

Comment: There are no properties on the built-in controls to enable such animations.  Office and the Mail app were both made by the Office team, and they use their custom animations library which they talked about at [this presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2015/2-776) on Build 2015.